# Difference of a mean and a median after logarithmic transformation

Tags: data-transformation, mean

I have a rather skewed sample, its skewness is about $3$. Then I use the logarithmic transformation, the skewness of the transformed sample becomes about $0.4$; the histogram also seems to become more bell-shaped, but the difference between a mean and a median increases after the transform! How can it be explained and interpreted?

I would like to note that the sample size is $400$, that seems to be good.

Comment: How can you say that the difference "increases" when the transformed data are *logarithms* and the original data are not?  The two kinds of values are incomparable.

Comment: Hm. They are, indeed, but we expect the data to become more normal...

Comment: Since you agree that the differences cannot be compared before and after the transformation, it looks like you don't have a question anymore: how can anyone hope to "explain and interpret" something we all agree makes no sense?

Comment: Not exactly, dear @whuber, I still have some incomprehension one the question. Perhaps, I need some time to understand it.

Comment: Maybe adding a plot of the histograms to your question helps in undestanding it